# how to get values from sql database by selecting combobox items in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, types

I'm trying this coding , what is the error in this coding:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =TWPL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TWPLSOFTWARE;Integrated security = True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ACC_ID ,ACC_TYPE ,ACC_ADD,ACC_CITY ,ACC_STATE ,ACC_COUNTRY ,ACC_TIN_N0 ,ACC_ECC_NO,ACC_RANGE,ACC_DIVISION ,ACC_COMMISS ,ACC_GST_NO ,ACC_CONTACT_PERSON ,ACC_PHONE_NO ,ACC_MOBILE_NO ,ACC_EMAIL ,ACC_PRICE_CODE ,ACC_APPROVAL_STATUS,ACC_PAN_NO from ACCOUNT where ACC_NAME='" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACC_NAME", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                textBox17.Text = dr.GetString(0).ToString();
                comboBox1.SelectedItem = dr.GetString(1).ToString();
                richTextBox1.Text = dr.GetString(2).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = dr.GetString(3).ToString();
                textBox3.Text = dr.GetString(4).ToString();
                textBox4.Text = dr.GetString(5).ToString();
                textBox9.Text = dr.GetString(6).ToString();
                textBox11.Text = dr.GetString(7).ToString();
                textBox13.Text = dr.GetString(8).ToString();
                textBox14.Text = dr.GetString(9).ToString();
                textBox16.Text = dr.GetString(10).ToString();
                textBox12.Text = dr.GetString(11).ToString();
                textBox5.Text = dr.GetString(12).ToString();
                textBox6.Text = dr.GetString(13).ToString();
                textBox8.Text = dr.GetString(14).ToString();
                textBox7.Text = dr.GetString(15).ToString();
                textBox15.Text = dr.GetString(16).ToString();
                //checkBox1.Checked=dr.GetString().ToString();
                textBox10.Text = dr.GetString(18).ToString();

            }                     

        }
```

this is my problem :

> "The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to
>   operator."

Comment: What is your error code? Please be more specific. Read [faq] and [ask] first.

Comment: what do you expect to happen and what *is* happening?

Comment: Why are you adding @ACC_NAME as a parameter when you already have it in query ?

Comment: you shouldn't pass Sql parameter to DB as it's normal query ,you shall pass it in stored procedures

Comment: One error (but not your issue, I guess) is that that parameter is *not* used. Use the parametername instead of the literal string in your query (`WHERE ACC_NAME=@ACC_NAME`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assing `@ACC_NAME` variable in your query first, then you are tring to add as a parameter again. Check out [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) from MSDN.

Try like this;

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ACC_ID ,ACC_TYPE ,ACC_ADD,ACC_CITY ,ACC_STATE ,ACC_COUNTRY ,ACC_TIN_N0 ,ACC_ECC_NO,ACC_RANGE,ACC_DIVISION ,ACC_COMMISS ,ACC_GST_NO ,ACC_CONTACT_PERSON ,ACC_PHONE_NO ,ACC_MOBILE_NO ,ACC_EMAIL ,ACC_PRICE_CODE ,ACC_APPROVAL_STATUS,ACC_PAN_NO from ACCOUNT where ACC_NAME=@ACC_NAME;", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACC_NAME", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

Also based on your error message;

> The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to
>   operator.

In your database, I think your `ACC_NAME` column type is `text`. That's why you are getting an error when you try to assing it in a string. You have two options;

- Change your `ACC_NAME` column type to `nvarchar` in your database. `Text` datatype is deprecated.
- Use `LIKE` operator instead of `=` in your `WHERE` clause. You can't compare against `text` with the `=` operator. Try;

> where ACC_NAME LIKE @ACC_NAME;

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which line gives you an error? Please be more specific. Did you read [ask] before asking this question?

Comment: SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();      line gives you an error: "The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a winform project and the error comes from the

```
comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

If comboBox2 is bound to a datasource, try to use SelectedValue or SelectedText

Otherwise you can also use the Text property of the Combobox also

Answer (score 0):

There is no @ACC_NAME parameter in your SQL query. Either modify your query like

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ACC_ID ,ACC_TYPE ,ACC_ADD,ACC_CITY ,ACC_STATE ,ACC_COUNTRY ,ACC_TIN_N0 ,ACC_ECC_NO,ACC_RANGE,ACC_DIVISION ,ACC_COMMISS ,ACC_GST_NO ,ACC_CONTACT_PERSON ,ACC_PHONE_NO ,ACC_MOBILE_NO ,ACC_EMAIL ,ACC_PRICE_CODE ,ACC_APPROVAL_STATUS,ACC_PAN_NO from ACCOUNT where ACC_NAME=@ACC_NAME;", con);
```

or remove the `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACC_NAME", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));` statement.

**EDIT :**

It seems that `comboBox1.SelectedItem = dr.GetString(1).ToString();` is causing the problem.
I would suggest using `comboBox2.Text = dr.GetString(1).ToString();` or better to set using `comboBox2.SelectedIndex`

Comment: Can you be more specific and tell which statement is causing the error ?